# Is it possible to make a mobile site using jQuery inside the ordinary html webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This is my first time asking questions here and I have just started learning jQuery mobile so if it is not quite relevant or if it is just really obvious I apologize in advance.

What I am trying to do is build a mobile site for an online catalog for lots of books.

The original website has a very sophisticated way of filtering and sorting the search results based on the user's input and preference so unless it's absolutely necessary, I would really like to keep the original functionality of the website.

I was thinking maybe I can create a "mask" that looks like a mobile site to cover the real content; and whatever the user requests, I will go "underneath" the mask, do the search and when the data is loaded in the original website, I will then present them in a more mobile-friendly way.

So here is my question:

Is it possible to somehow include/embed a mobile site in the original html?

If so, could you please give me a few hints (books, articles, tutorials, anything) as to how I can approach this?

If not, could you please tell me how I should make the mobile site without having to re-create all the nice functionality that original website already has?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: While not exactly what you're looking for, you should at least read about responsive design http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: thank you for the recommendation! I am new to web design as well so it's good to study these early on. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this but you shouldn't. Mobile websites are optimized for mobile users. Not only as layout but also in loading weight. The direction you are heading you end up with a regular side (probably big in load) and add an overlay (extra load) to rebuild the layout (CPU heavy). So it's not the right way. A better solution is to create a optimized layout for mobile users only.

Comment: I completely agree with you - it's just that the original website has so much functionality and it will take a really long time to rebuild everything for the mobile site... :( I consulted the guy who worked on a similar project and even though he built his mobile site from scratch, he recommended me to stick to the original site due to the search complexity...

Comment: Is there no way to try to wrap some sort of API around this search functionality to embed this as standalone item to the mobile version? You are absolutely making a terrible experience for your visitors if the only way is to create a wrapper around the regular site. Maybe it would be better to not create a mobile version to prevent the ilusion there is a 'optimized' site at all.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea but unfortunately I don't know enough about the APIs right now to implement it. However, in the future when I am working on my own projects like this, I will make sure to keep your suggestions in mind. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Too bad we couldn't really help you any further. Good luck with the project.